# Open a single file in blender via terminal with an unknown filename

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, filenames, blender

I would like to execute a `.blend` file via terminal in a directory where only one `.blend` file is located. I would like to start this file without knowing the exact file name.

If I knew the filename I would do it like this:

```
blender --background example.blend --render-output //filename --render-frame 1
```

Comment: OK, is the command right now? Please stop changing it.

Comment: @G-Man, sorry, but if it does not work, it does not help.Now it's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it’s the only file in the directory (or even the only `.blend` file),
all you have to do is run your command with a wildcard
(a.k.a. glob, a.k.a. pathname expansion):

```
blender --background *.blend --render-output //filename --render-frame 1
```